# How to retrieve folder's items in a specific order with box.com api?

Tags: box-api

I am trying to list items under a folder through box.com API. The documentation states it is possible to request the response sorted by, e.g. name of the items. How should the order part of the request be formatted?

https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?fields=name,description,created_at,id&order=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That attribute currently is not settable (it was included in the documentation by error). The returned sort order will reflect the sort order set in the user's Box account through the web app.

We're working on making order and actual settable attribute, but it's not yet released.

Comment: do you know it box.com made any progress? is the feature of retrieving list of documents in specified order available?